# Is there any way to determine an image's type from its GD handle?

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails, mime-types, exif

I am writing a thumbnailing script, and from what I've seen thumbnails tend to look best in the same format as their source. However, the script may be fetching images from the web, so I can't access the file twice. So is there any way to get the file type other than exif_imagetype and other functions that have to re-open the image? I don't want to rely on the extension as that can obviously be wrong.

I'm doing the thumbnail processing with GD, so something that uses the handle would be perfect, but I could also use the file's contents. And yes, I'm aware that GD handles reference uncompressed data, but I'm not sure that they don't remember what they decompressed from.

Comment: Why, what is wrong with `exif_imagetype`?

Comment: It has to open the image file. So if the image is on another server, it will be requested twice, once when I call `exif_imagetype` and again when I actually load the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getImageExt($bytes)
{
    $hex_bytes = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($bytes); $i++)
    {
        $hex_bytes .=  dechex(ord($bytes[$i]));
    }
    if (strncasecmp($hex_bytes,'FFD8',4) === 0) return 'jpg';
    if (strncasecmp($hex_bytes,'474946',6) === 0) return 'gif';
    if (strncasecmp($hex_bytes,'89504e47',8) === 0) return 'png';
    if (strncasecmp($hex_bytes,'424d',4) === 0) return 'bmp';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough solution. I'm going to wait and see if there is anything more concise before I accept it though (it seems like this should be built into something...).

Comment: Quick question - why are you converting all of `$bytes` and not just the first 8 bytes?

Comment: because I believe that it is responsibility of the caller to cut first 8 bytes from the image body. However, it could be changed to reference call and thus done in the function

Comment: Ok, cool. I decided to use your code and its working great. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
// with GD
$img = getimagesize($path);
return $img['mime'];

// with FileInfo
$fi = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
return $fi->file($path);
```

Comment: Thanks, but both of those require reading from the file, which would mean two requests if the image is hosted elsewhere and I later want to read the whole thing.